# Java: Raw anonymous class loses generic types in its methods

Tags: java, generics, anonymous-class, raw-types

I've been a bit nonplussed by this behaviour of Java compiler. Could somebody explain why this happens? Consider this example:

```java
public static abstract class GenericClass<A extends GenericClass<A>> {
  protected abstract void method();
  protected <B> B getB(Class<B> bclass) {
    return null;
  }
}
// ...
GenericClass<?> gc = new GenericClass() {
  @Override
  protected void method() {
    String s = getB(String.class); // does not compile
  }
};
String s = gc.getB(String.class);  // compiles
```

Because no generic parameters are given in the `new`, the anonymous class inherits from the raw type `GenericClass`. Even though the method `getB` does not mention `A`, the generic information is still lost and the method call does not compile. Why does this happen?

Further, the reason I cannot specify the generic parameter for the `new` is because it is supposed to be the anonymous class itself, but I cannot name the anonymous class to pass it. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw types exist for compatibility with code from before generics existed. They are treated as a full "opt-out" of all things generic. If you want generics, do not use raw types. That is the intent of the language design.

The solution here is to name the class. Yes, classes *can* appear inside methods and other statement blocks; such things are called local classes. An anonymous class is basically a local class without a name—and local classes can do anything anonymous classes can do.

```
String thisIsFine() {
    var cell = new Object() { String s; }; // example local variable to show local classes can access them
    class GenericImpl extends GenericClass<GenericImpl> {
       @Override
       protected void method() {
           cell.s = getB(String.class);
       }
    }
    new GenericImpl().method();
    return cell.s;
}
```

Comment: Local classes may solve the problem, thanks. Although I don't own the code that implements GenericClass, I can recommend this solution. At the same time I still don't quite get why raw type turns off _all_ generics, even those that don't directly participate in class type definition.

Comment: @NebehrGudahtt Because you do not usually specify generics at method calls. Pre-generics code may contain stuff like `GenericClass g = ...; g.getB(...)` and it will expect no generics checking at the call to `getB`. Post-generics, the syntax of the call `g.getB` doesn't change, because we usually leave method generics inferred. So most of the time the syntax does not signal to the compiler whether we want the raw type of a method or the genericized type. Therefore the rawness of the call *must be* chosen to be the same as the rawness of the receiver for compatibility.

Comment: but why does this same call work outside the class methods?

Comment: @NebehrGudahtt Because the type of the receiver is different. `GenericClass` is a raw type and for compatibility *all* generics on *all* of its methods must be erased but `GenericClass<?>` is a normal generic type and has the "right" types for everything.